# Word order: "bis zu vier gleichzeitig" vs "gleichzeitig bis zu vier"

Tags: word-order

> Du kannst jetzt **bis zu vier gleichzeitig** verwenden!
>
> {or}: Du kannst jetzt **gleichzeitig bis zu vier** verwenden!

I sometimes find myself vacillating between different possible placements of adjacent adverbs and prepositional phrases.

In the case of lining up *ja, doch, wohl, da, dann, dazu* – to name but a few – they seem to follow predetermined patterns and  I now feel comfortable enough with them, but in this particular case, the first choice seems just as likely as the alternative.

How can I determine which to place first?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use both.
The first one could be read more fluently - without breaks.
In the second one the emphasis is on "gleichzeitig" with a small break after it.

Comment: you are right...

Answer (score 0):

> Du kannst bis zu vier gleichzeitig verwenden!

Ist richtig :)

**EDIT**

Actually you can not say, that my initial answer is correct.. But it sounds more familiar to me, and I won´t use the other one.

The reason is, that the word order of the other example brings "gleichzeitig" into focus, while my favorite example has its focus on "bis zu vier".

It (as ever) regards to content. If it was possible, that you can use 4 pieces before, and the clou now is, that you can use them at the same time, the second example would be **correct**. If the new thing is, that you are able to use 4 and, because of context, at the same time is its natural consequence, the first example would ne **correct**.

Comment: But I can´t say anything about patterns.. Your examle word is not so easy  ;) and those "ja, doch, wohl" etc are one of the meanest things in german language.. Its a bit like using "though".. If you have got a feeling for the language, it will be much easier to use these words..

Comment: Und wieso ist das richtig?

Answer (score 0):

> **(a)** Du kannst jetzt bis zu vier [Blatt Klopapier] gleichzeitig verwenden!
>
> **(b)** Du kannst jetzt gleichzeitig bis zu vier [Blatt Klopapier] verwenden!

(a) and (b) are correct.

(a) fits better if in the past always one has been used (accent is on *»gleichzeitig«*).

(b) fits better if in the past two or three have been used (accent is on *»bis zu vier«*).